# Getting data from multiple tables without foreign keys in JPA 2.0

Tags: java, sql, jpa-2.0, postgresql-9.1

I've been stumbling upon followig issue for a couple of days now nad I can't make it to work. Here is the problem. I have four tables (A, B, C, D) which are not related to eachother via any kind of foreign key. Hovewer, they do have a column called, let's say,  'superId'.

The task is to take all the records from the A table, find records from the other ones with matching 'superId' (if they exist) and return them via JPA's constructor expression.

About JOINs. Since the tables have no relations, I can't do a left JOIN (or any other JOINs).

I tried to use MULTISELECT with a success, but it only works if I do an implicit joins with 'a.superId = b.superId'. This causes problems, since the three tables might not have matching records which will make the query to return empty set. This won't fly.

I have no other ideas, and this is crucial for my project to work. Please forgive me simple description of an issue - sending from my mobile.

Comment: A `JOIN` does not require a foreign key to be present.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you back it up with some reference or an example for JPA 2?

Comment: This is about JPA 2. I will edit the title

Comment: Can't you just annotate the classes with the foreign key constraint? Does JPA actually *verify* its presence in the database?

Comment: From what I've seen the syntax will not be valid in JPA if I try to do a regular join. Can you show an example of a SQL query for this? I could use native SQL query but I haven't tried that since I'm not sure if it will work. Would that be 3 left joins?

Comment: Here is a SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/125ee/1

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely do not require the presence of a foreign key relationship to perform an arbitrary query in JPA2.

You can't "follow" a parent/child relationship, so you can't do your usual `parentObject.childObject` thing. You must instead use the Criteria API, or HQL, to construct a join.

See:

- [Using the Criteria API to Create Queries](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html)
- [Creating Queries Using the Java Persistence Query Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)
- [JPQL language reference: joins](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbup)